# Is it possible to see an image as plane through a transparent object?

Tags: image, transparency, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to put transparent objects(using eevee) infront of an image imported as a plane. But I can't see the image through the transparent object. Is it possible to do that or am I wasting my time. Thank you in advance for your help!
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Just added it in the original question.

Comment: Can you add additional screenshots of your material and object settings? This will help the community to get a better understanding of your scene.

Comment: basically I'm just testing if this is possible, I don't have the final pics yet hah. Added more screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is possible.
You just need to enable the right blend modes.

1. Image plane - set blend mode to *Alpha Hash* or *Alpha Clip*
2. Glass - Set blend mode to *Alpha Blend*, and check *Screen space reflections*
3. Render tab - enable *Screen Space Reflections > Refraction*

[image]

Comment: You are a life saver! Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help :). When using Cycles instead of Eevee, it works right out of the box. Good luck with your project.